# Weblogic distributed queue - load balancing doesn't work

Tags: queue, jms, weblogic, distributed, cluster-computing

I have setup a weblogic 9.2M3 cluster server having two nodes on separate VMs.
On the cluster I have setup Uniform Distributed Queues shared in the cluster.
Unfortunately load balancing on the distributed queues doesn't work and all the messages are being processed by the clients on the same node as producer.

I have already checked the following:

1. Turned off Server affinity in the factory
2. Checked that multicast works between nodes in the cluster
3. Checked different ways of setting up targets for factory and queue by:

   - Setting the Factory and Queue to be deployed to Cluster and
   - Setting the Factory to Cluster and Queue to two JMSServers
   - Setting both Factory and Queue to be targeted to JMSServers

Any suggestions why the load balancing might not work with the configuration below?

This is the configuration I am using the portion of config.xml:

```
 <cluster>
    <name>TestCluster</name>
    <multicast-address>239.192.0.1</multicast-address>
    <multicast-port>17001</multicast-port>
    <number-of-servers-in-cluster-address>2</number-of-servers-in-cluster-address>
  </cluster>
  <jms-server>
    <name>JMSServer1</name>
    <target>server1</target>
    <persistent-store xsi:nil="true"></persistent-store>
    <temporary-template-resource xsi:nil="true"></temporary-template-resource>
    <temporary-template-name xsi:nil="true"></temporary-template-name>
  </jms-server>
  <jms-server>
    <nameJ>JMSServer2</name>
    <target>server2</target>
    <persistent-store xsi:nil="true"></persistent-store>
    <temporary-template-resource xsi:nil="true"></temporary-template-resource>
    <temporary-template-name xsi:nil="true"></temporary-template-name>
  </jms-server>
  <jdbc-store>
    <name>PersistentStore1</name>
    <prefix-name>sas1_</prefix-name>
    <data-source>QueueDataSource</data-source>
    <target>sas1</target>
  </jdbc-store>
  <jdbc-store>
    <name>PersistentStore2</name>
    <prefix-name>sas2_</prefix-name>
    <data-source>QueueDataSource</data-source>
    <target>sas2</target>
  </jdbc-store>
  <jms-system-resource>
    <name>ClusterJMSModule</name>
    <target>TestCluster</target>
    <sub-deployment>
      <name>ClusterSubDeployment</name>
      <target>TestCluster</target>
    </sub-deployment>
    <descriptor-file-name>jms/clusterjmsmodule-jms.xml</descriptor-file-name>
  </jms-system-resource>
```

The definitions of destinations:

```
<connection-factory name="jms/levelsInputConnectionFactory">
    <sub-deployment-name>ClusterSubDeployment</sub-deployment-name>
    <jndi-name>jms/levelsInputConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
    <load-balancing-params>
      <server-affinity-enabled>false</server-affinity-enabled>
    </load-balancing-params>
  </connection-factory>
  <uniform-distributed-queue name="jms/levelsInputQueue">
    <sub-deployment-name>ClusterSubDeployment</sub-deployment-name>
    <jndi-name>jms/levelsInputQueue</jndi-name>
    <forward-delay>10</forward-delay>
  </uniform-distributed-queue>
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps given in article http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=3747 and it helped me setup distributed queue for below given scenario...

(1-Admin Server (AS), 2-Managed Server (MS), 2-Boxes)

## Box-A

MS-1 under Cluster
JMSServer-1 and Store-1 => MS-1 (Migratable)

## Box-B

MS-2 under Cluster
JMSServer-2 and Store-2 => MS-2 (Migratable)

## Admin Server

- JMS_Module => Cluster
- SubDeployment_UDQ => JMS Server-1, JMS Server-2
- ConnectionFactory (with “affinity disabled”) => Cluster
- UDQ (Distributed Queue) => SubDeployment_UDQ

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.